# Why was I notified inbox without being tagged?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications, comment-replies

[combinatorics duplicates question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519122/combinatorics-duplicates-question)

In the above post when OP tagged trueblueanil, I got notified too why?

Proof:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment is addressed using "@trueblueanil", with I suspect that member having a previous comment there that was deleted. If that's true and this deletion occurred before the comment you're asking about was posted (or if there never was any comment from "true blue anil", although I consider that unlikely), then you would be notified instead because the only undeleted comments would then be from you. Note that "true blue anil" would likely not have been pinged, as I've noticed happening a few times myself in several similar situations (e.g., I comment about an issue, the OP fixes it, I delete my comment, and then the OP comments back (with "@JohnOmielan" being in the comment), but I'm not notified).

This behavior is described in the network FAQ Meta's [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/562482), in particular the Posts "comment" section third bullet point of the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/562482) which states:

> A post’s author comments on a post you have previously commented on, when the only other (undeleted) comments on the post belong to you or the author. (See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82134) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258816).)